# How to display data in a TableView based on the currentIndex in a ListView when both share the same model?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I have a `QListView` and a `QTableView`.
`QListView` shows the `request_group` of `Suite`

My question is: how to let `QTableView` display all `requestItem` values of `request group` which is selected in `QListView` and user can also edit,append and remove `requestItem` in `QTableView`,and update value in Suite.

I've already searched through the documentation. I'm wondering if I should use a ProxyModel, such as `SortFilterProxyModel` or `IdentityProxyModel`, or if it would be better to use a `QTreeView`?

##### Data schemas

```py
@dataclass
class RequestItem:
    method: Optional[str] = field(default=None, metadata={'QtHeaderName': 'Method'})
    url: Optional[str] = field(default=None, metadata={'QtHeaderName': 'URL'})


@dataclass
class RequestGroup:
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = field(default=None)
    requests: [RequestItem] = field(default_factory=list)


@dataclass
class Suite:
    groups: [RequestGroup] = field(default_factory=list)
```

##### Example Data

```py
suite = Suite()
r0_0 = RequestItem('GET', 'https://google.com')
r1_0 = RequestItem('GET', 'https://google.com')
r1_1 = RequestItem('GET', 'https://google.com')
r2_0 = RequestItem('GET', 'https://google.com')
r2_1 = RequestItem('GET', 'https://google.com')
r2_2 = RequestItem('GET', 'https://google.com')
g0 = RequestGroup('group0', 'desc0', [r0_0])
g1 = RequestGroup('group1', 'desc1', [r1_0, r1_1])
g2 = RequestGroup('group2', 'desc2', [r2_0, r2_1, r2_2])
suite.groups = [g0, g1, g2]

model_suite = ModelSuite(suite)
```

##### Qt Model

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QModelIndex, QAbstractTableModel


class ModelSuite(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, suite: Suite, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.suite = suite

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        # Set ListView rowCount to the length of requestGroup in suite
        return len(self.suite.groups)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        # Set TableView Header section count to the length of RequestItem properties
        return len(fields(RequestItem))

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role=None):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole or role == Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole:
            request_group: RequestGroup = self.suite.groups[index.row()]
            return request_group.name
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.ToolTipRole:
            return self.suite.groups[index.row()].description

    def setData(self, index: QModelIndex, value: Any, role: int = None):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole:
            request_group: RequestGroup = self.suite.groups[index.row()]
            request_group.name = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        ...
        return False

    def insertRows(self, row: int, count: int = 1, parent: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()) -> bool:
        ...

    def removeRows(self, row: int, count: int, parent: QModelIndex = QModelIndex()) -> bool:
        ...
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure, because the names you're using in the example data are not consistent with the classes listed above. The model contains a list of groups, each one containing a list of items, right? If that's the case, then you should consider a *tree* model, with the groups being the top level items (shown in the list view) and the children the items in each group. Then you just need to call `setRootIndex()` on the table for the selected item in the list. Do some research on implementing a tree model in PyQt, as there are a few examples on the web that show how it's done.

Comment: @musicamante Sorry if my initial question was a bit confusing. you are right, I have updated and revised my code, hopefully it can express my problem more clearly now. I will look into the tree model implementation that you mentioned. Thank you again for your help!"

Comment: What did you tried? Post a [mre]. Anyway, you don't need to use a tree or tree view. You need to create a new model(e.g. a ```QAbstractTableModel``` based one) for the ```QTableView```. And recreate or reset the model when the current index is changed.(e.g. using the ```QAbstractItemView.setModel()``` or ```QAbstractitemModel.beginResetModel()``` and ```QAbstractitemModel.endResetModel()```.)